# Break a Template Literals String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I have made an applet in IFTTT that gets my latest Instagram post's caption using `Instagram.anyNewPhotoByYou.Caption`.
All my Instagram captions are made up of 4 paragraphs.
This code stores the caption in a Template Literal multi line string:

```
const x = `${Instagram.anyNewPhotoByYou.Caption}`;
```

I want to divide the multi line caption into 4 strings (each containing 1 paragraph of my caption).

Is there any way to do that?

Sources:

- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [My Instagram account](https://instagram.com/unitedgiveaways) (If you want to see any of my posts' captions)

Comment: What separates each paragraph, a new line?

Comment: What is the exec result of console.log(Instagram.anyNewPhotoByYou.Caption); ?

Comment: @Vishal-Lia there is a blank line between each paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `Instagram.anyNewPhotoByYou.Caption` has paragraphs divided by a newline. Then use [spilt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method,

```
const x = `${Instagram.anyNewPhotoByYou.Caption}`;
let paras = x.split('\n');
```

Comment: Will `.split('\n')` create an array?

Comment: Yes! That's what split is used for. It returns an array of strings split using the delimiter we provide.